# File Handling not working in while loop

Tags: c++, file-handling

***Code:***

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>
 int n = 0, flag = 0,i;
struct bac
{
    char name[10];
    char amt[5];
} s;



void main()
{
ofstream f("C:\\TC\\1.dat");
     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     {

         cout << "\nenter the details ";
         cin >> s.name >> s.amt;

         f.write((char *)&s, sizeof(bac));
    }
    }
```

sometimes the code works fine 
 but at the other times , when i look at the output file,it is empty , the problem has come up many times , and i ant to know whether there is a precaution regarding loops with file handling

for eg. in other program

```
.....
while(ch!=4)
         {
        cout << "\nBANK MANAGEMENT SYSTEM \n";
        cout << "enter choice ";
        cout << "\n1.add\n2.search\n3.delete and overwrite ";
        cin >> ch;
        if (ch == 1)
        {
                cout << "\nenter the details ";
    cin >> s.name >> s.amt;
    f.write((char *)&s, sizeof(bac));
       }
  .....
```

the file is empty

Comment: You have a really outdated compiler if it accepts `iostream.h`. Use `<iostream>`, use `<fstream>`, and use `<string>` (unless you were actually going for C string functions). Also, use `int main`. A conforming implementation only accepts `main` with an `int` return type. Barring the C-style file io, there's no reason to create your object as a global. Keep it local to `main()`. Your input will also fail as soon as any user decides to type more than 9 or 4 characters. `std::string` fixes that painlessly.

Comment: i agree , but its compiling and the main question is  what could be the problem causing such diverse results?
even code#1 works using the same 
***iostream.h*** and ***void main()*** but works

Comment: It only works because your compiler is non-conforming and you use non-standard headers. If you want your code to work with someone else's implementation of C++, it's important to use standard C++, which all conforming implementations agree on.

Comment: i agree .. will edit the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may have used a very old compiler older than gcc 4.5.3.
I tried your code and it has no problem.

```
#include <iostream>  //use header file without using deprecated iostream.h
#include <fstream>   //same reason as above
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int n = 0, flag = 0,i;
struct bac
{
   char name[10];
   char amt[5];
} s;



int main()  //usually main returns int. void was kind of old now
{
    ofstream f("test.txt");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

        cout << "\nenter the details ";
        cin >> s.name >> s.amt;

        f.write((char *)&s, sizeof(bac));
     }
    f.flush();
    f.close();

    return 0;
 }
```

I compiled the code in gcc 4.5.3 and ran it. the file has all the stuff I entered. 
However, it will be better to use the << operator when you use file i/o stream to write to file.

You can find more information about  and  from top of this link:
http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html

Another point, wen you have done writing to a file, remember to flush and close the file handle, otherwise, sometimes it will cause some annoying problems.

Comment: thnx for the info, but still it doesnt answer one of my question ,

Comment: @Siddhartha Sinha Remember to flush and  close the file once you have done writing, that's may be the cause of why sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't seem very C++-like to me...
To answer the last question, there aren't any gotchas about fstreams in loops specifically, no.

I suggest first trying to do `f.write` with the members `name` and `amt` themselves—compilers might add padding between name and amt, creating unwanted garbage output.

Are you sure you have write permission to the filepath all the time? Try opening a local file, as in the path being simply "1.dat".

Also try opening the file as `f("/* file name */", ofstream::out | ofstream::app)`. "out" sets it as an output stream, and "app" makes it add to the end of the file. www.cplusplus.com/ofstream details more flags.

Comment: thnks for the suggestion , but i think i might have just found the solution

Answer (score 0):

since you are using c++, I suggest you use a formal way to use ofstream, in your code, it should be f << s.name << s.amt.

remember, you are using c++, so keep using i/o stream.

Comment: write is a member of ostream. using << is one way, it is OK to use write function

Comment: that may caused by the char[] type you using, in that case, you need to check the content very carefully, it may encounter too much cases here.